# Dynamically update datalist via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, html-datalist

I need to update a html 5 datalist via ajax.
Html code is here.

```
<body>
  <input type="text" id="bar" list="fruit" onkeyup="jsfun()" />
   <datalist id="fruit"></datalist>
</body>
```

A pseudo code of JavaScript.

```
function jsfun(){
    //1- Get the last word from input field ("bar").
    var skw1 = document.getElementById("searchBar").value;
    var skw2 = skw1.split(" ");
    var skw = skw2[skw2.length-1];
   //2- Use Ajax to send data on server and get data result back
   /* 
   * here goes other javascript content for ajax
    */
    xmlhttp.open("GET","searchopt.php?skw="+skw,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
   //3- use javascript to update the datalist with those result which Ajax get.
}
```

see the below url here first write **mang** then remove it and write **bann**
it give a suggestion
then remove it and know write **mango bann** this time it can not give any suggestion.why but the suggestion is prensent in database.it give suggestion only for first word.
http://iws.uphero.com/qwe.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok... here's the issue.  Datalist by default matches what is in the text box with the allowed options.  The options ARE changing properly via AJAX.  What isn't changing is that "mango bann" isn't equal to "mango" OR "bann".

As a workaround, you could use your AJAX function to overwrite the text box once a second word was entered.  For example:

```
var skw1 = document.getElementById("searchBar").value;
var skw2 = skw1.split(" ");
var skw = skw2[skw2.length-1];
document.getElementById("searchBar").value = skw;
```

Comment: I did not need whole thing.just need the last word like a google suggestion on every word.

Comment: It works as expected for me.  I type in "mango bann", and it returns "bann".

Comment: Yes it returns "bann" but problem is that it can not give suggestion about this.If you sepratly write "bann" then it give suggestion

Comment: In Safari, I'm not getting any suggestions.  It just ends up with the word "bann" over my text "bann".

Comment: If you're wanting to replace a DDLB or something, you really have to replace the whole thing... you can't use InnerHTML to replace only the options.

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand what are you saying.

Comment: So... datalist doesn't work at all in Safari (or IE 9 or earlier).  I cannot see any error in the code.  Safari confirms that the exact same GET parameter is sent, and the exact same data is returned.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28386/discussion-between-user2280065-and-lawson)

Comment: Lawson please give any response in chat